# Error while deploying profile using Apex Metadata API

Tags: apex

I am trying to deploy profile using apex metadata api . I am getting the following error

profiles/Standard Platform Usercopy.profile (Line: null: Column:null) : duplicate value found:  duplicates value on record with id: .

Have no idea What is the issue. Please help?

Comment: Yay for obscure errors. Presumably, it is a duplicate value, but it could be anything from a duplicate pick list value to a duplicate record type. If you manually built the file, try instead retrieving a valid file from the server, then modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience migrating profiles using API / Partner tools or change sets doesn't provide very good results - I mostly prefer doing manual updates whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says I'd guess there's a duplicate in there.

Unfortunately the only solution is to get choppy with your profile. If its under revision control then start there with the last known working version and look at what's been introduced.

Otherwise start deleting entries until it deploys,  then put some of them back and see if it deploys. Repeat. Essentially a binary search.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to insert ..just changed the logic to update and all works fine!

Comment: @Sneha definitely write that as an answer :)